# <component-scan> fails when migrating application from Spring 2.5 to 3.2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I've got an application that was developed with Spring 2.5.5 using the XML-driven model.  I'm trying to migrate it to Spring 3.2.9 and use an annotation-driven model of development.

I'm using ant as my build tool, rather than maven, as that's what was originally used and that can't be changed.

I've downloaded the Spring 3.2.9 libraries and updated my ant build.xml file to reference the ones that I need.  My spring config file (jsradmin-servlet.xml) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="uk.ac.glasgow.mis.hr.jsrwebadmin" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="exceptionResolver" class="uk.ac.glasgow.mis.hr.jsrwebadmin.web.controller.HRCErrorController" />

</beans>
```

I'm deploying this to a JBoss 5.1.0 server but when I do so, I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: I/O failure during classpath scanning; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Applications\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy\jsradmin.war\WEB-INF\classes\uk\ac\glasgow\mis\hr\jsrwebadmin (The system cannot find the path specified)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:302)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4122)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4421)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor318.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:362)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Applications\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy\jsradmin.war\WEB-INF\classes\uk\ac\glasgow\mis\hr\jsrwebadmin (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:128)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:136)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:73)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingJarResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:458)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:344)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:268)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1269)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:257)
... 92 more
```

My package in the `<context:component-scan />` line is definitely correct.  In fact, if I change it to, say,

```
<context:component-scan base-package="uk.ac.glasgow.mis.hr.jsrwebadminxxx" />
```

The application deploys correctly, although obviously without scanning the packages, so my controllers and other components fail to register correctly.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Raj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please upgrade to `3.2.10.RELEASE` (or even better, the 4.x line). This was an issue that was introduced in that specific version (see [SPR-11887](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11887))

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!  I was going cross-eyed staring at my code trying to find a non-existent typo! (Oh, and as far as I know, Spring 4 doesn't support JBoss 5, so we have to stick with the 3.x line)